# IntelliJ IDEA code completion on Java External Library

Tags: java, intellij-idea, code-completion, jetbrains-ide

I imported some java external libraries.  I'm trying to configure my "IntelliJ IDEA 15 CE" code-completion feature to pick up the classes and methods in these external libraries.

I spent a couple hours trying to figure this out, so is this even possible?

Thanks.

Comment: IntelliJ should pick them up when you add the jars to either the `dependencies` tab (in module settings), or as project or global libraries.

Comment: I've done all that. It works because the external libraries are listed on the sidebar, but it doesn't seem to translate into code-completion.

Comment: Have you tried this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6652540/rebuild-intellij-project-indexes

Comment: Does it have to be a certain file type and not .java or .class files? Thanks!

Comment: .jar, .java, .class should all work

Comment: I saw that post and it didn't work.

Comment: Is there something else should I do in addition to adding the jars to the dependences table in the module settings or as libraries?

Comment: Have you checked the settings to make sure autocompletion is on? in Editor > General > Code Completion

Comment: Yes, but there doesn't seem to be the option of whether to turn code completion on or off. It still works for the basic methods, but none of the external library methods.

Comment: If you don't have any important settings, try delete the settings folder (`.IdeaIC15` in your home folder, might be hidden), and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: I'm not finding it in my mac. I also re-installed it just a minute ago, and still got the same results.

Comment: See this link for the folder locations https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544519-Directories-used-by-the-IDE-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs

Comment: Okay i found it. But this makes me a little nervous. Why would deleting .IdeaIC15 solve the issue?

Comment: Just wondering if some settings might be messed up. You can back them up before deletion.

Comment: I just did that. No luck. Just reinstalled it again to be safe.

Comment: I guess it's not a feature of the community edition.

Comment: Auto completion definitely works on community edition. Works here with no problem. Unfortunately cannot help you figure out the problem.

Comment: It's all good. I decided to switch to eclipse several minutes ago and it works perfectly. Thank you for your help.